# chef node installation help (bootstrapping)

Tags: centos, chef, installation

I am attempting to bootstrap my first node in Chef. I set-up my environment as the following

Server: Centos 6.5 running Private-chef-11.1.8 (casino.xxx.com)

Client: Centos 6.5 running chef-client 11.12.8 (zodiac.xxx.com)

Node: Centos 6.5 running chef-client 11.12.8 (hop.xxx.com)

I am running the following from my client, so it can be registered with the CHEF server

```
knife bootstrap hop.xxx.com -x root -p *******
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

I am however able to SSH to this client as normal:

```
[root@zodiac .chef]# ssh hop.xxx.com 
The authenticity of host 'hop.xxx.com (192.168.1.145)' can't be established. 
RSA key fingerprint is 0f:56:db:87:44:8d:6e:ff:e6:96:c0:50:e6:75:f4:c9. 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
Warning: Permanently added 'hop.xxx.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. 
reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for lt8168.xxx.com [192.168.1.145] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT! 
root@hop.xxx.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again. 
root@hop.xxx.com's password: 
Last login: Fri Jul 18 15:28:20 2014 from 192.168.1.173 
[root@hop ~]#
```

Can you explain why knife is not able to connect? Is knife using port 22 to connect? (I have not changed any settings from the default) Does it require additional ports opening or is there a possible issue with my configuration?#

*Edit* Ive checked /var/log/secure on the node which I am trying to bootstrap and nothing is being logged when the command is being run

Comment: Is there anything in the ssh logs on the server when knife runs?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the most simplest of solutions are hardest to spot.

I was using lower case -p to connect to the server lowercase p actually specifies a port and -P (upper case) specifies a password.....